# Vector Layer not visible in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping

I'm trying to create a map where I have one wms layer and then a vector layer which is created from a kml file - held in the same directory as the web page.

I'm trying to implement the cluster strategy but to no avail. I think I might me going wrong even before the cluster strategy kick is in as I can't see the vector layer at all when I remove the wms layer?

This is the code for the vector layer:

```
var map;

function init() {
   map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});
   var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    'WMS Layer Title',
    'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
    {layers: 'basic'},
    {}
);

var masts = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Masts", {
projection: displayProjection //EPSG:4326,
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
url: "masts.kml",
format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        extractStyles: true, 
        extractAttributes: true
        })
}),
strategies: [
new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),
new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
],

styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
"default": {
        fillColor: "#8aeeef",
        strokeColor: "#32a8a9"
        }
     })
});

var StaffTravel = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("StaffTravel", {
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "staff.kml",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()
}),
strategies: [
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(),
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance: 15, threshold: 3})
]
});

map.addLayers([StaffTravel]);
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check out from console when adding my code to your app if your kml file is loaded or not? beside this you should glance at this example [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Dynamic_KML) and [here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-July/025733.html).

```
var StaffTravel = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("StaffTravel", {
projection: displayProjection //EPSG:4326,
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "staff.kml",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true
                })
}),
strategies: [
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),
    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
],

styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": {
                fillColor: "#8aeeef",
                strokeColor: "#32a8a9"
                }
                    })
});

map.addLayers([StaffTravel]);
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Hi Aragon, i tried your code out in a basic

Comment: ..openlayers page and it still didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

'

Comment: Just realised i can't fit the code in here. Relatively new to this as you might tell. I post it in answer below.